# How to add multiple printer profiles for a network printer on Windows XP?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

I have several computers connected to a single network printer. I want to add a second profile for the network printer so that I can give it different printing properties (landscape vs portrait).

We are using Windows XP. The network printer has an address like:

```
\\SERVERCOMPUTER\Dell Laser Printer M! Dell Laser Printer M5200
```

How can I add a second printer profile or a network printer?

Comment: Set up another print queue in the same way. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried to add a printer in the same way. Add Network Printer > Browse for Printer > choose printer. However it does not actully add a second profile, it just reverts back to the same profile.

Comment: IF you browsing for a printer then your not creating a new queue...... You need to create another printer with the settings you want.

Comment: Indeed. So how should I do this with a network printer? There are two other options: 1. Connect to this Printer  2. Connect to a printer on the Internet or a home/office network - I have tried both using the address of the printer and the IP address. Neither work. The address above has spaces in it so not sure if this is causing issues. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to complete this on \ServerComputer for this to work.ONce you have created the second shared printer you will need to add it to the clients that need this printer. But the basics are below.

Open Printers and Faxes, Under Printer Tasks, click Add a printer to
    open the Add Printer Wizard, and then click Next. Click Local
    printer or stand-alone network printer, clear the Automatically
    detect and install my Plug and Play printer check box, and then
    click Next. Click Create a new port, and then click Standard TCP/IP
    Por  Click Next to run the Add Standard TCP/IP Printer Port Wizard.
    Follow the instructions on the screen to finish installing the
    TCP/IP printer.

Set up the printer how you want it to be set up and share.